# finding resources for OSX plug-in

Tags: macos, dynamic, bundle

I have an OSX bundle which includes an executable shared library with associated
resources (think of photoshop).

How can I find the bundle that contains the plugin and resoruces at runtime?

`_NSGetExecutablePath()` and `GetMainBundle()` get the main application, not the
running plugin code.

The bundle doesn't have a fixed path, it's in some random plugins folder
located by the plugin host.   Likewise it doesn't have a unique name, as
there could be many different versions of the "same" plugin associated
with different versions of the plugin host.

If i have a chunk of executing code which was loaded as part of a bundle, there ought to be an unambiguous way to reference the resources from the same bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is to call `CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier` or `[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:]`.

As documented for [`CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier):

> For a bundle to be located using its identifier, the bundle must already have been loaded. The principal purpose for locating bundles by identifier is for code in frameworks or **plugins to find its own bundle**.

And for [`[NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/bundleWithIdentifier:):

> This method is typically used by frameworks and plug-ins to locate **their own bundle at runtime**.

Answer (score 1):

You use `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[SomeClassUniqueToYourPlugin class]]` to get your plug-in bundle and then the various `NSBundle` resource location methods from there.

Comment: two related but not identical releases of the same plugin would have the same classes, wouldn't they?  And c based plugins would have no classes.

Comment: The Objective-C runtime doesn't cope well with the same class being loaded from two bundles. So, plug-ins have to ensure that their classes will be unique across all plug-ins that may be loaded into the same process. This is a thorny problem, but it's orthogonal to this question. For C-based plug-ins, you could use `+bundleWithIdentifier:` or `CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier()`, instead.

Comment: that sounds like a major bug to me - if I make a class with the same name as some other vendors class, and something breaks as a result.